# QGIS stacked bars diagram -added data

Tags: qgis

This is a supplementary post to my previous questions which shows a map with stacked bars. There are six attribute fields (integer) with values of 0 (or null) to 60. The length of the bars does not reflect the individual data values. In some cases (shown as dots), the bars do not display at all. This seems to occur when there are only one or two fields with non-zero values.I would like to get a stack of rectangles the length of each is linearly related the value in each of the fields in the attribute table.

Comment: Difficult to say without sample data or screenshot